# Magnetic Field a Small Distance off of the Z-Axis of a Loop of Current

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

We were given: The $\:z\boldsymbol{-}$component of the magnetic field due to a loop of wire is
\begin{equation} 
\boxed{\:\:B_z\boldsymbol{=}\dfrac{\mu_{0}IR^2}{2\left(R^2\boldsymbol{+}z^2\right)^{\frac32}}\:\:}
\tag{01}\label{01} 
\end{equation}

[image: small distance off of a loop of current]

and are trying to find the radial component of the magnetic field a SMALL distance from the $\:z\boldsymbol{-}$axis.

We have to use the divergence of the $\:\mathbf{B}\:$ field being $\:0\:$ to calculate this. What I did was set the divergence of $\:B_z\:$ to equal to the divergence of the radial component (in cylindrical coordinates). I attempted to solve this, but it ends up being
\begin{equation} 
B_{\rho}\boldsymbol{+}\rho\dfrac{\mathrm dB_{\rho}}{\mathrm d\rho} \boldsymbol{=}\dfrac{\mathrm dB_z}{\mathrm dz}
\tag{02}\label{02} 
\end{equation}
and I have no way to isolate $\:B_{\rho}$. My professor said this problem is not hard, so I feel like I am just missing a key point of understanding. Thanks for any help!

Question source: My professor designed this question, no textbook.

Comment: Why does your formula call the distance along the $z$-axis $x$ instead of $z$?

Comment: You are also being inconsistent about whether the radial-from-axis coordinate is called $\rho$ or $r$.

Comment: There is no such thing as “the divergence of $B_z$” or “the divergence of $B_\rho$“. There is only “the divergence of $\mathbf B$”.

Comment: @G.Smith I fixed it. Sorry, I had to find reference images since I couldn't type the equation. The radial from axis coordinate is called r in my notes, but the photo shows    .

Comment: I've added the homework-and-exercises tag. In the future, please add this tag to this type of problem. This is one of the things that we ask you to do in our homework policy: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange

Comment: Please reference the source of this homework question. This is one of the things that we ask you to do in our homework policy: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange

Comment: Please edit your question to mark up your math using mathjax. Here is a sample: $y=ax^2$. If you right-click on the sample equation, you'll see some ways to access documentation or look at the mathjax markup.

Comment: It may help to write the divergence in cylindrical coordinates in a different way, as [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence).